# Map causing invalid -- expected a string error

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting an error that appears to be related to my array map function. If the array contains an object the page renders correctly, however, if it is empty then the page doesn't load and I get an error in the console.

**Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.**

What am I missing here?

Path: `Companypage`

```
export default class CompanyPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const { companies } = props;

    this.state = {
      companies,
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { companies } = nextProps;
    this.setState({
      companies,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <tbody>
        {this.state.companies.map(company => (
          <tr key={company._id}>
            <td>
              <img src={company.companyImageURL} alt="Company image" className="img-rounded company-image mr-2" />
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-link"
                onClick={this.handleDeleteCompanyImage(company.companyImageURL, company._id)}
              ><FontAwesomeIcon className="fa-fw" icon={faTimes} /></button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <Link to={`/admin/application_components/edit/company_details/${company._id}`}>{company.company}</Link>
            </td>
            <td>{company.firmSize}</td>
            <td>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-link"
                onClick={this.handleDeleteCompanyCollection(company.companyImageURL, company._id)}
              ><FontAwesomeIcon className="fa-fw" icon={faTrash} /></button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          ),
      )}
      </tbody>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you using the component, can I see the import statement?

Comment: This is the component. I just cut out the rest of the table to keep it short.

Comment: Also there is a comma after the `)`. Also rememebr to wrap in a table

Comment: Are you default importing it or named importing it?

Comment: maybe use this? `onClick={() => this.handleDeleteCompanyCollection(company.companyImageURL, company._id)}`

Comment: Sorry guys. The error was coming from missing elements within the object. Thanks to @Kunukn you put me on the right path.